# Service taking too much space

Tags: android

In my application I have a service in which I have a timer which is called every 3 seconds.
Inside  `onTick()` function I am accessing a URL and getting the result.
When I run the application this service is taking more than 30 MB.
Please help me if there is another method other than timer to call a function every 3 secs.

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 10000)
{
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NEXT CALL ...Dev:" + android_name + "ID:" + android_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        acceptPairing();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() 
    { 
        timer.start();
    };
}.start();
```

Inside `acceptPairing()` I am doing the `httppost` call.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you are leaking any memory.

Make use of the MAT plugin in the eclipse.

Don't try to hold the object reference unless it is required.

Comment: I am Using httppost inside this call.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the app run in the background as well?
2. You can use a local variable, say,

> static int timer = 100;
>   ...
>
> > > timer--;
> > >
> > > > if (timer<=0) {
> > > >
> > > > > //fetch the url
> > > > >
> > > > > > timer=100;
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > }

Just a suggestion!